# Python context manager: is it possible to modify error object in __exit__?

Tags: python

Here is a context manager:

```py
class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elapsed = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = perf_counter()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.stop = perf_counter()
        self.elapsed = self.stop - self.start
        if exc_type:
            # modify error object
        return False
```

I would like to add a prefix to all error messages that raised inside this context manager.

```py
with Timer() as t:
    raise ValueError("error occurred!")
```

which will print `Within Timer: error occurred!`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elapsed = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = 5
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.stop = 5
        self.elapsed = self.stop - self.start
        if exc_value and exc_value.args:
            msg = exc_value.args[0]
            new_msg = "In Timer: " + msg
            exc_value.args = (new_msg, *exc_value.args[1:])
        return False

with Timer() as t:
    raise ValueError('hello world')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 19, in <module>
    raise ValueError('hello world')
ValueError: In Timer: hello world
```

The first arg of the exception is the message, so you just modify it and then leave the rest of the args as they were